# Redirecting Nginx root to subdirectory without causing a redirect loop

Tags: nginx

I am trying to setup my nginx server to do the following:

1. redirect www to non-www
2. serve the foo.htm file from the en folder while the browser address bar displays https://domain.com/en/foo for all of the following URLs:

   - `http://domain.com/en/foo`
   - `https://domain.com/en/foo`
   - `http://domain.com/en/foo/`
   - `https://domain.com/en/foo/`
   - `http://domain.com/en/foo.htm`
   - `https://domain.com/en/foo.htm`
   - `http://domain.com/en/foo.html`
   - `https://domain.com/en/foo.html`
   - `http://domain.com/en/foo.[any extension]`
   - `https://domain.com/en/foo.[any extension]`
3. redirect root domain to a subfolder: `https://domain.com/` -> `https://domain.com/de`

So long I managed to do 1. and some parts of 2. Whenever I try setting up 3. I get a redirect loop

My config file looks like this:

```
http {

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name www.domain.com;
        return 301 $scheme://domain.com$request_uri;
    }

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  domain.com;

        location / {
            root /srv/www/domain.com/;
            index  index.html index.htm;
            try_files $uri.htm $uri/ =404;
            # the following line causes redirect loop:
            rewrite ^ example.com/de permanent;
        }

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: create a separate `location = /` and do (3) there.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That worked. I had to add this: ´location = / {
            rewrite ^ /de permanent;
        }´

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cause redirect loop because it will rewrite even if the URL is http://example.com/de

```
rewrite ^ example.com/de permanent;
```

If you just want to redirect the http://example.com to subfolder, you can follow @sendmoreinfo way:

> create a separate location = / and do (3) there.

And if you want to redirect all to /de:

```
if ($request_uri !~ /de/) {
    rewrite ^ http://example.com/de permanent;
}
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate your help! Any ideas on requirement (2) so that it works for all the cases in the list?